# How load 'chrome-extension' in the mozilla firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

In google chrome I do it like this:
`extensions` ->`developer mode` -> `load unpacked`. And how to do it in the browser `mozilla firefox`. Do you need to add something to the `manifest.json` file?

My file `manifest.json`, which I use in the `google chrome` browser:

```
{
  "name": "EXTENSION",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+A"
      }
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "https://*/",
   "http://*/"
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: see if you can solve it yourself by [reading the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: The correct MDN link is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox).